# jasmine protractor typescript to continue execution after one expected failure in it block

Tags: typescript, protractor, jasmine2.0

I am using protractor-jasmine framework with typescript -

so i have multiple it blocks within describe , so within each it block there are many methods or expect conditions i am verifying-

so currently when one of the expect failed then whole it block is terminated , so i want to continue the execution even after one step fail.

Below is **Spec.ts**

```
it('Should display Introduction screen with title correctly', () => {

    page.navigateTo('/');

    console.log('Verifying  Title is displayed...');
    expect(page.getTitle()).toBe('Quick Refund Estimator');

    console.log('Verifying button -Estimate my taxes is displayed..');
    expect(page.getButtonText_EstimatesMyTaxes()).toEqual(true);

});
```

**Po.ts** as below -

```
export class IntroductionPage {

navigateTo(url: string): void {
    browser.get(url);
    browser.waitForAngular();
}

getTitle() {
    return element(by.className('qreTitl')).getText();
}

getButtonText_EstimatesMyTaxes() {   
    return element(by.buttonText('Estimate my taxe')).isDisplayed();
}
```

In current scenario when below methods fail then further execution is stopped but i want to continue all step execution

```
getTitle() {
   return element(by.className('qreTitl')).getText();
}
```

Could you please help me,

Comment: Have you tried to add `ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true` in protractor conf.js.  More detail at here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L547

Comment: Tried this but getting this error and exiting from execution on first failure -->Error= E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

Answer (score 0):

The fact that stops I believe is the intended behavior.

Anyway, you could maybe try with:

```
jasmine --stop-on-failure=false
```

here is the [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/node.html#section-21).

Comment: where should i add this -jasmine --stop-on-failure=false. I am using protractor.conf.js and i am not using spec/support/jasmine.json

Comment: @simond,  `--stop-on-failure` only work when you run jasmine script by jasmine cli from cmd line. For protractor,  it's no way to use this option.

Answer (score -2):

I use for the same purpose such library https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-stop-describe-on-failure 
 . 
Describe block will stop executing it blocks after first fail to minimize test runtime.

You should install this library 

`npm install protractor-stop-describe-on-failure --save-dev`
 
 and then in your protractor configuration file, register the reporter in jasmine:

```
const DescribeFailureReporter = require('protractor-stop-describe-on-failure');

exports.config = {
   onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(DescribeFailureReporter(jasmine.getEnv()));
   }
```