# mocha protractor typescript to continue execution after one expected failure in it block

Tags: protractor, mocha.js

I am using protractor-mocha framework-

so I have multiple specs for the test,
Currently, when one of the e2e.js failed then the whole will be failed, so I want to continue the testing with others e2e.js.

```
module.exports.config = {
  framework: 'mocha',
  directConnect: true,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['incognito', '--disable-gpu'],
    },
  },


  specs: [
    'e2e/use_cases/login/login.e2e.js',
    'e2e/use_cases/create_user/create_user.e2e.js',
    'e2e/use_cases/update_user/update_user.e2e.js',    
  ],
};
```

Comment: I want if login.e2e.js failed, then can continue the create_user.e2e.js.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640562/jasmine-protractor-typescript-to-continue-execution-after-one-expected-failure-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running all these 3 specs in sequence which I see you are and if you are using bail or exit flag as true for mocha then the test execution will stop on first failure. This is because a single node process is running the tests one by one and on first failure that single process gets exited.

So if you are running test in sequence then what you are trying to achieve is not possible , to stop executing the failure spec(login.e2e.js) and continue with other specs(create.e2e.js)

However if you can run the tests in parallel then on failure in login.e2e.js will not stop create.e2e.js test execution. As in this case separate node process is running these specs individually so exiting one process does not impact other node process.

If you want to run tests In parallel , just add two properties in capabilities in protractor.conf.js
shardTestFiles: true,
maxInstances: 1,